# Python Spark, Accessing Class Static Variables from Executor

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a class which has some static variables keeping my code's configurations. I initialize the variables in the master and want to access them in the executors. What I see is that when I use them in the executors they are not initialized. Wondering how I can initialize the variables in the executors.

```
class EnvVariables:
    attributes = {}
    allTags = ["UNK"]
    similarityDicts = []
    mergeThreshold = 0.5

def readAttrConfig(cpath):
    EnvVariables.attributes.update(BLAH)
    EnvVariables.allTags.append(BLAH)
```

When I print the variables in the master, I see they have correct values, but in the executors they are not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. Python classes are imported independently on each executor so any changes you apply on a driver won't be visible in the executor threads. Since Python classes are not serializable it is not technically possible to propagate these changes.

Probably the simplest solution here is to pass required configuration using objects  which are initialized on the driver, can be serialized and passed to the executors.

Alternatively you can use `SparkFiles` to distribute configuration files and read these when module containing `EnvVariables` is imported:

- `envvariables.py`

  ```
  from pyspark import SparkFiles

  class EnvVariables:
      attributes = {}
      allTags = ["UNK"]
      similarityDicts = []
      mergeThreshold = 0.5


  with open(SparkFiles.get("config")) as fr:
      EnvVariables.attributes.update({"a": 1})
      EnvVariables.allTags.append("b")
  ```
- main script:

  ```
  from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkFiles

  sc = SparkContext()
  sc.addFile("config")

  from envvariables import EnvVariables
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up putting all the code in one file and broadcasting an object of the class.

Comment: @Majidgh can you please tell how did you broadcast an class object.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'not initialized'? The values in your class on all workers will remain to reflect -

```
attributes = {}
allTags = ["UNK"]
similarityDicts = []
mergeThreshold = 0.5
```

They will retain these values over all workers. They will of course not be updated on every worker (when updated on one of them) as they exist on different machines.

Broadcast variables come in handy in such place where you want consistency among variables which are bound to change on workers.

For cases where these variables are read-only or you want them to be existing separately for each worker such as kafka producers, cloudant databases the way you have described works fine.

I think the phrase "not initialized" should be updated to "not updated".